# SDHC 4GB - lost data including photographs

Tags: data-recovery, sdhc

For some reason my memory card has lost all of the data on it - probably about 150+ precious photographs. I thought the camera was faulty, but now realise that it must have been the card. My husband has changed the card, and when we have tried to download photographs from the original it is showing 'no files'. I do not know if they have been accidentally deleted, or if something else has happened to erase the card.

What are my chances of being able to  retrieve the photographs? If I attempt to do this myself, which is the best programme to use? Would I be better off taking it to a computer expert to try to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 5):

### How can I get my photos back?

1. Does the camera allow you to connect it with the computer? Perhaps the storage is non-standard?
2. Run a program like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) against it, which is made exactly for this purpose.
3. Perhaps something changed on your computer, try another one.
4. Perhaps it is stored in Linux format? Try a [random LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) (don't install, just work on it) to see if it helps.
5. If those things don't help, more advanced forensics are required. A computer expert (which I read as your local computer supplier) might or might not be able to recover it, it's worth trying but it could cost you some money depending on the situation.

### How could this happen?

- Did this work before? Then it might just be an incorrect way of accessing it.
- My guess is that there has been a magnetic force near the SD, if not, it might've been a power bump?
- Perhaps your SDHC card is getting old or used a lot and had it's time?

Comment: Yeah, I'd try a photo recovery tool.  I think there are people who even buy "blank" used SD cards just to recover what might have been on them (and also old cameras that still have undeveloped film in them).